# can't access the Amazon s3 data by query string authentication

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

My codes below is used to access the amazon s3 to get a .zip file .
and my request url is like this:
`http://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/Pack1A.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEMQY4BEQUOCUP7Q&Expires=1298945115&Signature=sxoXZ4y7osXjn
IycQynGbE9%2Bb5E%3D`

Code Snippet:

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime); 

gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Authorization","AWS AKIAIEMQY4BEQUOCUP7Q:aN6bjwDkeZXIHDrqk3MHlj4shl0%3D");
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Authorization", buf);
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Accept","application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*;q=0.5");
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-GB");
gHttpDownloader->SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
gHttpDownloader->Post(gURL, NULL,0,GotHeaders, NULL);

............ //GotHeaders is a callback function that reads input from the response.
```

It always prints the error of 403 forbidden. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that all ACLs are set correctly.

The example URL is using `Query String Authentication` but the code example shows setting the `Authorization` is being set. You only need to set one or the other. See the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

There is also a AWS [PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/code/).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue where requesting the pre-signed URL from a web browser was successful, but directly from PHP resulted in failure. After doing some digging, I learned that to simulate a web browser, you need to pass a `Content-Type` header with an empty value.

The [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) provides the following sample in the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url):

```
<?php
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

// Generate the URL
$url = $s3->get_object_url('my-bucket', 'folder/file.txt', '5 minutes');

// Try to fetch the URL so we can get the status code
$http = new CFRequest($url);
$http->add_header('Content-Type', ''); # Simulate a web browser
$http->send_request(true);

echo $http->get_response_code();
#=> 200
?>
```